# The printed outputs being broken when doing parallel computation by multiprocessing module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, alignment

I suspect this might be a classic problem but I've couldn't find the keyword concerning this issue so I'm here to ask for advice.

Considering the following code regarding multiprocessing module in Python

```
import multiprocessing

def parallel(n):
    while n <= 10000:
        n += 4
    print(n)
    
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
    n = [0,1,2,3]
    results = pool.map(parallel, n)
```

You can test the code at [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)

The problem I want to solve is that, I want the printed outputs to be aligned nicely. Such as

```
10003 

10001

10002

10004
```

The outputs don't have to follow any increasing or alphabetical order, I just want those outputs to be aligned throughout the multi-lines.

For the example code I've attached above, it works fine in my VSCode.
However, I observe that it gets broken in [Sage Cell server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)

as,

```
100011000210003 
  
10004
```

or

```
1000410001 10003 10002
```

If it was just a problem happening in Sage Cell server, I would have just skipped it and use my personal IDE. However, when the code gets bigger and complicated I've observed that it also happens in my personal IDE of `PyCharm` and `VSCode`.

So, is there any promising method that I can avoid those breakage between the multi-line printed outputs? Looking forward to any kind of advice. Thanks.

> [What I've tried]

I've tried

`print(n, '\n')`

method. But it didn't work out.
It seems obvious that another method is required to deal with this problem.

> [Edit for the Clarification]

For a clarification of my problem, I would like the outputs to be aligned throughout several lines. Such as,

```
10004

10001

10002

10003
```

If outputs are printed as

```
10004 10001 10002 10003
```

then, it is surely better than

```
100041000110002 10003
```

However when my desired outputs are not just short integers, but long sentences with some calculated integers inside those sentences, I need them to be printed out throughout multi-lines in alignment.

```
1. ~~~~~~~10004~~~~~
2. ~~~~~~~10001~~~~~
3. ~~~~~~~10002~~~~~
4. ~~~~~~~10003~~~~~
```

If they are printed out as

```
1. ~~~~~~~10004~~~~~ 2. ~~~~~~~10001~~~~~ 3. ~~~~~~~10002~~~~~ 4. ~~~~~~~10003~~~~~
```

Then, the readability becomes bad. So I need them to be aligned throughout the multi-lines.

Any advice would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: you can do `print(n, end=" ")`

Comment: @Hackaholic: Thanks for the comment. But I've tried at Sage Cell server immediately but it is still broken. You may observe that by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [format](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

```
print(" {} ".format(n), end="")
```

you can also use short hand syntax

```
print(f" {n} ", end="")
```

for multiline output you return the result from the function parallel

```
import multiprocessing

def parallel(n):
    while n <= 10000:
        n += 4
    #print(f" {n} ", end="")
    return n
    
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
    n = [0,1,2,3]
    results = pool.map(parallel, n)
    for i,x in enumerate(results):
        print(f"{i}~~~~{x}~~~~")
```

output:

```
0~~~~10004~~~~
1~~~~10001~~~~
2~~~~10002~~~~
3~~~~10003~~~~
```

Comment: Wow. It works great! Just my one last wish... can I print it throughout multi-lines? I'm desiring to print some longer outputs such as "1. ~~~~~", "2. ~~~~~", "3. ~~~~". So I need them to be printed out multi-lined for the readability. The short hand syntax also works great! But I hope I could see the just one last step of advice for the alignments between multi-line outputs. Still, many thanks!

Comment: can you give a sample in the post for multiline? I am not able to understand